# What does "toward the ends of peace and the happiness of all mankind" refer to?

Tags: meaning

I am watching this movie about the bombings of Hiroshima and Nagasaki:

https://archive.org/details/Effects-Of-The-Atomic-Bomb-On-Hiroshima-And-Nagasaki-1946

In the final scene 2:43:55 - 2:44:10 the speaker says this:

"The day may come when atomic energy used for the first time in the world for strategic, military purposes will be utilized toward **the ends of peace and the happiness of all mankind**. So is it desired. So is it hoped. And so is it believed.”

I don't fully understand the meaning of the "ends of peace and the happiness of all mankind". Can you please explain it to me? Is it a metaphor for "forever"?

Comment: Your key clue to the meaning is "ends."

Comment: One of the meanings of "ends" is "goals; aims". From this you might be able to deduce the meaning of the whole phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ends** in the sense of:  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/61863?rskey=qUrjjo&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> 14 An intended result of an action; an aim, purpose. (Cf. Latin
>   finis.) to accomplish one's end(s), to answer one's end(s), to fulfill
>   one's end(s), to gain one's end(s)

As in:

> "The day may come when atomic energy used for the first time in the
>   world for strategic, military purposes **will result in** peace and
>   the happiness of all mankind. So is it desired. So is it hoped. And so
>   is it believed.”